# Can you help me and check my sentences using Either, Neither, So, and Too?

Tags: word-usage

I write sentences and have a problem with the understanding of too/either, So am I/Neither do I.

Can you check my sentences and correct mistakes?

1.

– I ate a tomato.

– I ate it too. (So did I.)

2.

– I don’t eat ice cream.

– I don’t eat it either. (Neither do I.)

3.

– I’ve had dinner.

– I’ve had dinner too. (So did I.)

4.

– I like candies.

– I like them too. (So do I)

5.

– I like watching TV series.

– I like watching them too. (So do I)

6.

– He likes playing basketball.

– I like playing too. (So do I)

7.

– I went to the shop today.

– He went to the shop too. (So did he)

8.

– I killed the mosquito.

– I killed one too. (So did I)

9.

– I don’t want to dust.

– I don’t want to either. (Neither do I)

10.

– I can’t play hockey.

– I can’t either. (Neither can I.)

11.

– I can’t cook soup.

– I can’t either. (Neither can I.)

12.

– I have not written one sentence.

– I have not written one either. (Neither have I)

13.

– I can’t speak French.

– I can’t either. (Neither can I)

14.

– I have never swum in a pond.

– I have never swum either. (Neither have I.)

15.

– I have never fished.

– I have never fished either. (Neither have I)

Comment: I haven't written a single sentence. =idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the auxiliary for the verb:

- He likes apples. = So do I.
- He doesn't like apples. = Nor or neither do I.
- I don't either.
- He ate a tomato. = So did I.
- He didn't eat a tomato. = Nor or neither did I.
- I didn't either.
- He's had dinner. = So have I.
- He hasn't had dinner. = Neither or nor have I.
- I haven't either.

You have to use the **auxiliary verb or modal verb (should or would) that matches the tense.** I am not going to go through the entire list. You now have the pattern and if you are not able to pick out the auxiliary for the tense, you won't will be able to do it.

- He will go tomorrow. = So will I.
- He won't go tomorrow. = Neither or nor will I.
- He shouldn't do that. = Neither or nor should I.
- He should do that. = So should I.
- He was going today. = So was I.

etc. etc.

That's the basics. With modals like might, it can be slightly more complicated but we'll leave that for another time.

Comment: Shouldn't I write like that: I ate a tomato. - I ate it too.? Should I write that: I ate a tomato. - I did too. Is it?

Comment: You can't both have eaten the same tomato! _I ate one too._

Comment: Alexander: I ate a tomato. I [different person] ate a tomato too. I did too. So did I.